# Is there a program that can download mail from a server and deliver copies locally?

Tags: linux, email, mail-server

Is there an open source application that can download e-mails from a generic POP mail server, keep a copy of the mails locally and then deliver copies to multiple accounts on a LAN? I have a friend who uses a group e-mail account, and more than one person is always hooked onto that account. The problem is they cannot leave e-mail on the server, as it eats out their webhosting space, but if someone downloads a message in Outlook, the other users do not see that message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchmail` can download messages from POP3 and distribute them to [multiple recipients](http://www.fetchmail.info/fetchmail-man.html#43).

The *real* problem, however, is sharing a single mailbox. All current mail servers support pointing a single alias (for example, `support@domain`) to a group of recipients.

Comment: fetchmail isn't available for windows but I guess aliasing will solve the problem, thanks a ton

Comment: @Kumar: You tagged your question with `Linux`. Expect Linux answers.

Comment: I realised later that my deployment platform isn't Linux :(